# Assigning values of an array all at once in Delphi without using a loop

Tags: arrays, delphi, properties, assign

Is it possible to assign values of the same type at once?

In my case I have a custom component derived from TComponent which I call TBox.

TBox has the property **Left** in it.

I have an array of TBox and would it be possible to assign the property **Left** to all
the TBox component all at the same time without using a loop?

Setting the value **Left** using a for loop:

```
  var BoxArray: array [0..9] of TBox;
      i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    BoxArray[i] := TBox.Create(nil);
    BoxArray[i].Left := 0;
  end;
end;
```

I would like to do the above without a for loop, or any kind of loop to be honest.
I would like to apply new value to **Left** without iterating through each TBox
but simply apply the new value to all of them instantly.

Comment: What does instantly mean? If it means what I think it means, then you are going to be disappointed. It's going to be hard for us to answer your question if you don't say what `TBox` is. It might also help if we knew why loops were to be avoided. One also wonders how you are going to call `Random` multiple times without some form of iteration. Essentially, this question seems to imply some misunderstanding somewhere. I think you need to clarify.

Comment: Ok sorry. I don't know if I should maybe use the word simultaneously instead. Yes. That sounds better. Simultaneously. TBox is simply a virtual-graphical-component. No need to go in-depth about it. It is some OpenGL stuff. I used the value Random as an example. It might as well be BoxArray[i].Left:=0;

Comment: You don't want to give us detail? Fine. Does that mean we can answer and omit all the detail? Are you happy for me to write an answer that says, *You cannot do this, but don't worry about the detail, you don't need to know.* I doubt it very much. Surely you can see the difference between assigning the same value, and assigning different values to each item, the value being the result of a function call. How can you call `Random` multiple times without iteration? I still don't understand why you are scared of a 10 iteration loop.

Comment: The detail of TBox is very important to the question.

Comment: Ok the details are basically that I have over 1 thousand GLScene objects which I need to present in form of a horizontal list and I need to move them left or right with the mouse. And iterating though each TBox might take a small amout of time. Especially since I will have several "lists" presented to the user, so maybe 20 thousandobjects all in all will be in the 3D space. So I am guessing that using a loop to go through each and every one of them might take some time, and I am asking if there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: Impossible to answer perf issues without details. Please reconsider your approach and put more effort into preparing a question that contains the current code, benchmarks, and desired performance. It has already become clear that you don't care whether or not you use a loop, what you really care about is performance.

Comment: So to answer your question: Yes, if your answer is a simple Yes or No, please be my guest. I came here for an answer, and any answer is welcomed since this is a project which I can't leave any considerable amount of details. But there you have it. The details.

Comment: I'm just asking, is there a way to apply 1 value to many components  simultaneously. If it's not, then alright. If there is a solution, I'd like to know.

Comment: Well, in the question you actually demonstrate code that applies 10 different values, each requiring a function call. Details matter.

Comment: Have you actually identified the loop as being a performance issue? I'd suspect that unless you're dealing with millions of items in the array, the loop will be much less an issue than you think. (But the answer is no, you can't do it any other way.

Comment: Not really a performance issue. Just asking out of curiosity and for the sake of making my code cleaner.

Comment: The point is that if TBox was something like `TBox = record Left: Byte; end` then You could easily do a `FillChar(BoxArray[0], 10, 50)`. That is why we need all of the details.

Comment: Can implement a getter that would check a global or the like before returning the backing field.

Comment: @Graymatter I see. But I noted out specifically that TBox is derived from TComponent.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz would you like to elaborate?

Comment: @Graymatter `FillChar` is implemented using iteration

Comment: I know, I was just trying to give you an example of why it's important for us to see as many details as possible. Often there are different ways of achieving the same thing which makes the full picture really important.

Comment: function GetLeft: Integer; begin if GlobalLeft <> -1 then Result := GlobalLeft else Result := FLeft; end;

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I thought it used memset internally although I am not certain what the assembler is generated for that. I will have to double check. There is a good chance that ultimately there would be a loop involved but it's not always a certainty. For example, the SIMD stuff has ways of setting a number of values through the extensions.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I see. but that would require iteration as well. The GetLeft would need to be called somehow.

Comment: @xaid - GetLeft is supposedly getter of the Left property. Won't you have the same problem if you assign all Lefts at once? Won't have to read that Lefts later?

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to do the above without a for loop, or any kind of loop to be honest. I would like to apply new value to Left without iterating through each TBox but simply apply the new value to all of them instantly.

If you need to write to multiple memory locations, then some form of iteration is required. Even if you find a way to write the code at a high level so that no looping or iteration is visible, somewhere along the way there will need to be iteration.

If your goal is to improve performance, then I'm afraid that we would need to see a lot more detail in order to be able to give specific help.

Comment: Is it possible to use 1 pointer to point to several method adresses or something? I recall that using MethodAddress() in TComponent will return the same address regardless from which TComponent it is as long as the Method Name is the same. Maybe that could evolve to a solution by using pointers instead?

Comment: No. One pointer refers to one single address in memory. I don't really want to go into more detail since you've insisted that the question be of a very general nature.

Answer (score 0):

As David Heffernan already sad it is not posible to write multiple memory locations at once which means that it is not posible to modify multiple variables or multiple fields at once.
Technically you could change miltiple properties at once but only if all of these properties read the same field since changing the field value would affect all properties that reads it.

Now in order for you to make your code look a bit nicer you could modify your TBox constructor so that it also accepts aditional optional parameters for initial variables.

```
type
  TBox = class(TComponent)
  ...
  public
    consturctor Create(AOwner: TComponent; Left: Integer = 0; Top: Integer = 0); override;
  ...
  end;

...

implementation

...

constructor TBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent; ALeft: Integer = 0; ATop: Integer = 0);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  self.Left := ALeft;
  self.Top := ATop;
end;
```

So now you can create your TBox in two ways:

```
BoxArray[i] := TBox.Create(nil);
```

Will create your TBox with defult position parameters that are defined in constructor method implementation.

```
BoxArray[i] := TBox.Create(nil, 5, 10);
```

Will create your TBox with position parameters you passed to the constructor method.

NOTE: Optional parameters are read from left to right and you can not skip one in the middle.

```
BoxArray[i] := TBox.Create(nil, 5); //Is valid and top will be 0 (default value)

BoxArray[i] := TBox.Create(nil, , 10); //Is not valid and will raise compiler error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you use TArray and a constructor instead of array of TBox;

```
TBox = class
    left, right : Integer;
    constructor Create(l,r : Integer);
end;

constructor TBox.Create(l,r : Integer);
begin
    left := l;
    right := r;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender : TObject);
var
    boxes : TArray<TBox>;
begin
    boxes := TArray<TBox>.Create(TBox.Create(1,2),TBox.Create(5,10));
end;
```

Comment: This entails iteration